# Ruby: Why don't we need `attr_accessor`?

Tags: ruby, csv, methods

I just ran through an example from the 1.9 pickaxe book and I'm confused why the following program runs successfully without using `attr_accessor` in the `csv_reader.rb` file.

book_in_stock.rb

```
class BookInStock
  attr_accessor :price, :isbn

  def initialize(price, isbn)
    @price = Float(price)
    @isbn = isbn
  end
end
```

Aren't we writing to the instance variable of the csv_reader object by appending new BookInStock objects to it?

csv_reader.rb

```
require 'csv'
require_relative 'book_in_stock'

class CsvReader
  def initialize
    @book_in_stock = []
  end

  def read_in_csv_data(csv_file)
    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
      @book_in_stock << BookInStock.new(row["price"], row["isbn"])
    end
  end

  def total_value_in_stock
    sum = 0
    @book_in_stock.each {|book| sum += book.price}
    sum
  end
end
```

test_data.csv

```
"price","isbn"
"44.12",'asdf34r13'
"74.12",'asdf34r13'
"14.12",'asdf34r13'
"42.12",'asdf34r13'
"4774.12",'asdf34r13'
"04.19",'asdf34r13'
```

Program Driver

```
require_relative 'csv_reader'

reader = CsvReader.new

ARGV.each do |csv_file_name|
  STDERR.puts "Processing the thing"
  reader.read_in_csv_data(csv_file_name)
end

puts "Total Value = #{reader.total_value_in_stock}"
```

Is the `read_in_csv_data` method doing the same job as an accessor method?

Comment: In the `total_value_in_stock` method, you call `BookInStock#price` which isn't available without the `attr_accessor`. Thus, I strongly doubt that your program works if you leave out the call.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now but I was referring to the @book_in_stock instance variable and my main confusion was why are we able to write to it/set it without declaring something like `attr_writer :book_in_stock` at the top of the class. But Max down below cleared up my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr_accessor` creates two methods that would look roughly like this if you were to write them by hand:

```
def price
  @price
end

def price=(new_price)
  @price = new_price
end
```

You are never calling any of those methods, so it is irrelevant whether they exist or not.

Comment: I'm calling the price method in `total_value_in_stock`. So, that could just be `attr_reader` I suppose. But, I'm referring to the `csv_reader.rb` file where, if I understand correctly, am writing to the instance variable of that object. How can I do this without an accessor method? That is what I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: You are not calling the method. You are assigning to a variable.

Comment: Instance variables are always in scope inside the class, so you don't need accessor methods to read/write them. You can use the variables directly.

Comment: Instance variables are always in scope inside the *instance*, that's why they are called "instance variables".

Comment: I was referring to the price method being called on `book`